# How to write a regex to delete shortcodes with varying wording

Tags: html, regex, wordpress

I have shortcodes that I would like to delete placed in hundreds of WordPress posts that look like this :

```
[ratingTable id="26" theme="3" rank="1" desc="Play This Top Rated Site For Free!"]
```

However, they each have text which is different after the initial [ratingTable id=”26” part. How could I create a regex that would identify all of these from that first bit of text and select the entire shortcode? Thanks!

Comment: The first step in creating a regex is probably learning how regular expressions work, and what they can and can't do. There are a [ton](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) of [tutorials](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285) which [you](https://www.rexegg.com/) can [follow](http://regextutorials.com/) to [learn](https://regexr.com/). I suggest you start with those.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this with regex

Find:

```
\[ratingTable(?=\s)(?=(?:[^\]"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\sid\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*26\s*\1))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^\]]*?)+\]
```

Replace: nothing

https://regex101.com/r/4B9RtX/1

```
 \[ ratingTable                # Begin tag
 (?= \s )
 (?=                           # Asserttion (a pseudo atomic group)
      (?: [^\]"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      \s id \s* = \s*               # id = 
      (?:
           ( ['"] )                      # (1), Quote
           \s* 26 \s*                    # 26
           \1 
      )
 )
                               # Have the id, just match the rest of tag
 \s+ 
 (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^\]]*? )+

 \]                            # End tag
```

Comment: Ty, but it needs to begin with the text [ratingTable id="26". Not just [ratingTable. How would I add that part?

Comment: Thank you this looks good, but do you have any experience with the Search Regex WordPress plugin? When I search this it says zero results, but there are many.

Comment: @Bill - That plugin uses Php regex which is PCRE. All constructs in this regex use PCRE. You must be inputting it incorrectly, or using the search and replace incorrectly. I'm not the person to ask since I have never used wordpress or that plugin. I suggest you contact the author or go to their forums with usage questions. However, this is the regex you need. See [In addition to simple searches you have the full power of PHP’s regular expressions at your disposal](https://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/search-regex/)